# Multi Line Graph D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to plot more than one line on my graph as per this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

The data is being pulled from a mySQL database using PHP - with output in following format:

```
 [{"dateTimeTaken":"2013-02-21 07:39:29","reading":"12.2","parameterType":"Flouride"},
 {"dateTimeTaken":"2013-02-21 07:39:34","reading":"12.01","parameterType":"Temperature"}, 
 {"dateTimeTaken":"2013-02-2107:39:39","reading":"12.01","parameterType":"PH"},...etc.
```

I would like one line per parameterType but not having any luck getting it working.  At the moment getting an error "Problem Parsing d" and no lines at all displaying.

https://gist.github.com/Majella/ab32fe0151fd487da3f6

I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me understand where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried console.logging the value of `d` to see if the problem is not just a plain javascript problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `data.map` call -- it's supposed to return the modified object you want in the result array. To fix, simply modify `d` and return it.

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3azQX/).